# Unable to use VSCode CLI from extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create an extension and want to use 'code --version' inside child_process, but always it is return version of 'node'. from commandline I was able to use code --version without any issue.

Code:-

```
var output = child.spawnSync("code",['--version']);
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`${output.stdout}.`)
```

One thing I have noticed is always 'code' is considered as 'node' with in child process. Could someone help me to identify the cause of this issue.

Thank You.
Chaithanya

Answer (score 0):

Found that the process is running under VSCode installation folder which have code.exe. After changing code to below lines, it started working as expected.

```
const bat = child.execSync('bin\\code --list-extensions');
console.error(bat.toString());
```

Thank You.